# When predicting with an LSTM in Keras, is the hidden state still adjusted?

Tags: sequence, keras, prediction, lstm

When I first train an LSTM in Keras on sequence data - my training data -
 and then use `model.predict()` to make predictions with my test data as input, is the hidden state of the LSTM still being adjusted?

Comment: What do you mean by 'adjusted'?

Comment: Is the output of the test predictions being fed back into the node or is there no recursion anymore during model.predict()?

Comment: I think your question is if the recurrent state information (ex. previous output that's fed into the model with the next batch) updates when using predict. The answer is yes, you can see this for yourself by running predict on the same sample and you will get different outputs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic operation of a neural network is to take an input (vector) which is connected to the output with connections and, sometimes, other layers such as context layers. These connections are modelled as matrices and vary in strength, we call these *weight matrices*.

This means that the only thing we do when we are feeding data into the network is to put a vector into the network, multiply the values with the weight matrix and call that the output. In special cases, like recurrent networks, we even keep some values stored in other vectors and combine this stored value with the current input.

During training we not only feed data into the network, we also compute an error value that we evaluate in a clever way so that it tells us how we should change the weight matrices we multiply our inputs (and possibly past inputs for recurrent layers) with.

Therefore: **yes**, of course the basic execution behavior does not change for recurrent layers. We are just not updating weights anymore.

There are layers that do behave differently during execution time because they are treated as regularisers, i.e. methods that make training the network more efficient, which are deemed as unnecessary during execution. Examples for these layers are `Noise` and `BatchNormalization`. Almost all neural network layers (including recurrent ones) include drop-out which is another form of regularisation which disables a random percentage of connections in the layer. This is also only done during training.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I think I got the hidden states and the corresponding weight matricies mixed up.